# Camera skews objects when they’re near the outside of the frame

Tags: rendering, objects, camera

Im very new to blender, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I’m following a tutorial of modeling a room, and I’m using a background image inside of the camera to help me place my objects. I noticed that when I moved an object to the edge of the camera frame, it becomes skewed somewhat diagonally, and it messes up the perspective of the room. When I move the object back to the center of the frame, it looks parallel with everything else again. This problem also appears in renders. I didn’t see this problem in the tutorial, though the person was using an older version of blender. I’m not sure if this is a bug, a setting, or if it’s just normal. I’m out of ideas at this point, and would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you posted a screenshot of the camera settings!

Comment: if you use a camera the lines will distort according to the perspective, if you want to have a perfectly orthographic view you need to either use the 3D view in orthographic mode or create a camera and in the Properties panel (on the right by default) > Camera > Lens > Type, choose Orthographic instead of Perspective